# cs50 pset7 houses syntax

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error, cs50

I'm working on the `roster.py` part of the problem and I'm getting the error:

```
   File "roster.py", line 17
    print(f"{row["first"]} {row["middle"]} {row["last"]}, born {row["birth"]}")
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code:

```
import sys
from cs50 import SQL

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Needs two command-line argument")
    exit(1)

db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

house = sys.argv[1]

results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE house = ?", house)


for row in results:
    if row["middle"] != None:
        print(f"{row["first"]} {row["middle"]} {row["last"]}, born {row["birth"]}")
    else:
        print(f"{row["first"]} {row["last"]}, born {row["birth"]}")
```

Comment: Are you trying to print row["first"] or row["+first+"]?

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear? Probaly you want to escape the quotes that should not end the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong. Try this:

```
for row in results:
    if row["middle"] != None:
        print(f'{row["first"]} {row["middle"]} {row["last"]}, born {row["birth"]}')
    else:
        print(f'{row["first"]} {row["last"]}, born {row["birth"]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the row["middle"] value and so forth use this.

```
for row in results:
    if row["middle"] != None:
        print(f"{"+row["first"]+"} {"+row["middle"]+"} {"+row["last"]+"}, born {"+row["birth"]+"}")
    else:
       print(f"{"+row["first"]+"} {"+row["last"]+"}, born {"+row["birth"]+"}")
```